# How to split logs into monthly, daily and hourly folders when bringing in syslog events?

Tags: configuration, syslog, rsyslog

I am bringing in log files via rsyslog and my config looks like the following:

```
root@rhel:/etc/rsyslog.d# head mail_prod_logs.conf
if $fromhost-ip=="10.10.10.10" and $programname=="AMP_Logs" then -/var/log/mail_logs/amp.log
```

My logs are all stored in the `/var/log/mail_logs/amp.log` folder:

```
Oct 18 13:29:28 server.com AMP_Logs: Info: Begin Logfile
Oct 18 14:29:28 server.com AMP_Logs: Info: Version: 12.1.0-000 SN: .....
Oct 18 14:29:28 server.com AMP_Logs: Info: Time offset from UTC: -14400 seconds
Oct 18 15:29:23 server.com AMP_Logs: Info: Response received for.....
Oct 18 15:29:23 server.com AMP_Logs: Info: File reputation query.....
Oct 19 13:29:23 server.com AMP_Logs: Info: Response received for fil....
Oct 19 13:29:58 server.com AMP_Logs: Info: File reputation query ....
Oct 19 13:29:58 server.com AMP_Logs: Info: File reputation query ....
```

I would like to use the `datetime` portion of the log to put these in hourly folders inside of daily folders inside of the month while the data is coming in by editing the `mail_prod_logs.conf`.

So it would look like:

```
/var/log/mail_logs/Sep/30/23.log
/var/log/mail_logs/Oct/01/00.log
/var/log/mail_logs/Oct/01/01.log
/var/log/mail_logs/Oct/01/02.log
...
```

How can I do this?